# How to hide path to Database Backend from users without permission to view it?

Tags: ms-access, vba

My backend database is stored in a shared folder on the company network which I hide from users.

But if someone who doesn't have access to that shared folder open the frontend database then the database produces the error message:

> Path is not valid

...with the complete path of the backend database.

I don't want MS Access to show the path address in the message since I don't want people to know the backend file location.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried catching the error and re-directing to a custom message box?

Comment: No, I don't know how to catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

I used Microsoft Help and found the following code to hide the path and replace the message with my own. I copied and pasted the following code on my form on error event and replace the message.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
Select Case DataErr
    Case 3024
        MsgBox "You don't have enough permission to read/write data from Share Folder of Production Plant Division.", vbCritical, "Warning"
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        DoCmd.Quit
    Case 3044
        MsgBox "You don't have enough permission to read/write data from Share Folder of Production Plant Division.", vbCritical, "Warning"
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        DoCmd.Quit

    Case Else
        Response = acDataErrDisplay
        DoCmd.Quit
End Select
ActiveControl.Undo
```

End Sub